# Node Not Being Added Into Heap in Chronological Order

Tags: java, file-io, data-structures, heap

The function of my program is to allow a user to manage a list of Tasks using a Heap. The Current Task is based on the soonest due date. The task object contains 2 Strings a Name and a Due Date. I have no problem adding the Task Node to the Heap. My problem is that it should be adding it to the Heap and it should become the current task whenever the due date is coming up. My program works perfectly whenever I don't add anything, its only when I add a Task that the new task becomes the last task no matter what I set the due date to. Here are some examples:

```
Do Math Homework, 05/04/2015 11:00 // Read in from text file and added to heap
Do Grocery Shopping, 05/03/2015 12:00 // Read in from text file and added to heap
Write Code, 04/30/2015 15:00 
// User is asked for input and wants to add "Write Code" to Tasklist, notice the date.

Output when I run program:
Do Grocery Shopping, 05/03/2015 12:00 // This is correct order
Do Math Homework, 05/04/2015 11:00 // This is correct order
Write Code, 04/30/2015 15:00 // Problem here
// The added task always gets output last no matter what the date is
```

Main Class:

```
public static Heap addTask( Heap h ){
    Task newTask = new Task( "", "" ); // Create a new empty task.

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Task Name: ");
    newTask.setName( input.nextLine() );
    System.out.println("Enter the Due Date: ");
    newTask.setDueDate( input.nextLine() );

    Node n = new Node( newTask ); // Sets the data of new task and adds to Node.
    h.addNode( n );
    return h;
}
```

Task Class:

```
public class Task {
    private String name;
    private String dueDate;
    public Task( String n, String d ){
    name = n;
    dueDate = d;
}
// Maybe my compareTo() is wrong?
public int compareTo( Task t ){
    return dueDate.compareTo( t.getDueDate() );
}
```

Heap Class:

```
public class Heap {
private ArrayList<Node> heap;
public Heap(){
    heap = new ArrayList<Node>();
}
public int getPLoc( int i ){
    return ( i - 1 ) / 2;
}
public Node getNodeAt( int i ){
    if( heap.get(i) == null ){
        System.out.println("Item does not exist.");
        return null;
    }else{
        return heap.get(i);
    }
}
public void addNode( Node n ){
    heap.add(null);
    int index = heap.size() - 1;
    while( index > 0 && getNodeAt(getPLoc(index)).getData().compareTo( n.getData() ) > 0 ){
        heap.set(index, getNodeAt(getPLoc(index)));
        index = getPLoc(index);
    }
    heap.set(index, n);
}
```

Comment: Why date as String?`private String dueDate;`. There should be proper dateTime comparison. In this comparison there is error.

Comment: @Rahul I used String because the user inputs the date and time all in one line. Should I make a dateTime variable?

Comment: yes, it should be Date otherwise in string comparison, you will get wrong result.

Comment: You should use a time-related type, such as `util.Date` in Java 7 or `java.time.LocalDateTime` in Java 8. And convert the date into it.

Comment: @Rahul And how would I modify my `compareTo()` method?

Comment: Date class overrides the compareTo() method. so you can use Date objects as d1.compareTo(d2). It will return  if both datetime are equal, 1 if d1 is greater and -1 if d1 is less than d2.